# Disabling certain commands/programs in certain folders?

Tags: unix

Is there anyway to deny access to certain commands and executables while in a certain folder?

Specifically, I am trying to deny the access of pwd while in certain folders, so that users that access the folder via a symlink cannot see where in the file hierarchy they are (in order to prevent some security issues), but are able to use retain use everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move pwd to another directory and make a script called pwd like this:
provided new location of real pwd is /path/to/movedpwd:

`#!/bin/sh

if test /path/to/movedpwd = UNWANTED_DIR

then echo "Forbidden dir!"

else pwd fi`
Then make it executable-only so that the users cannot find the real pwd.